# perl, mysql - fasting way to upload a csv file into mysql?

Tags: mysql, perl

what is the fastest method to upload a csv file into mysql via perl, mysql?

The csv file is probably about 20Gs.

thanks

Comment: A better question would be *why* you would ever want to do that.

Comment: Restoring a backup, migrating DB hosts, set up a test instance, prepare for stress test evaluation, …

Comment: I'm with Brian - why do this through Perl? What's wrong with the standard loader or a purpose-built bulk-loader tool?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

consider using mysql LOAD DATA INFILE

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use Perl and DBI to execute a LOAD DATA INFILE statement, if for some reason you couldn't use the mysql client or mysqladmin.