# Importing csv into mysql (List of Codes)

Tags: php, mysql, csv

So I have a list of codes (100,000) to be exact and I got them delivered in a csv file.

I want to put theses codes in a database so I can later get them using my php script.
However my question is how do I get my codes from the file in the right table?

This is what my database looks like at the moment.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMxqC.png]

The codes from the file need to be inserted in table code.
Hope someone can help me out with this one.

Comment: Since I am looking at a screenshot of PhpMyAdmin, why don't you go ahead and click on the 'import' link in PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: you should have a look at this answer for a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536923/perl-mysql-fasting-way-to-upload-a-csv-file-into-mysql/9536990#9536990

Comment: can you show your excel file format.....?

Comment: importing didn't work it messed up the database only gave empty tables.

Comment: This is your firend: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably will find this helpful (pls adjust the table and others names):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'codes.csv'
INTO TABLE codes
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS; 
(@id,code,@active)
SET id = null;
SET active = '1'
```

More details:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

you can upload your csv file and post it. then use this function.

this is the PHP code:

```
function get_csv_file($filename){
if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== false) {
$filesize = filesize($filename);
$firstRow = true;
$aData = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, $filesize, ";")) !== false) {
    if($firstRow) {
        $aData = $data;
        $firstRow = false;
    } else {
        for($i = 0;$i < count($data); $i++) { //only for csv file
            if($data[$i] != '')
            $aData[] = $data[$i];
        }
    }
}
//print_r($aData);
fclose($handle);
$finalscrap = array_unique($aData);
     // echo "<pre>";
     // print_r($finalscrap);
     // echo "<pre/>";
return $finalscrap;   //this is your record as array format
}
}
```